# How to access nested child node using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

This the code, I need to access the second `<p>` element using javascript, I have tried many things unable to access it. Please help me on this

```
<div class="demo">
  <div>
    <p>Some Text...</p>
    <p><b>Author:</b> Author Name</p>
    <p>Some Text...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why not use a class/id on the tag?

Comment: for customizing auto-generated code by third party app, so unable to use clss/id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the second `p` tag using `nth-child`. I have colored the text red, for demonstration purposes.

```js
let p = document.querySelector(".demo div p:nth-child(2)")

p.style.color = "red";
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  <div>
    <p>Some Text...
    </p>
    <p><b>Author:</b> Author Name
    </p>
    <p>Some Text...
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getElementsByTagName()` and get the second element in the list.

```
const secondP = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get element by their tag name check this documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName

```
const allParas = document.getElementsByTagName('p'); // collection of all p tags
allParas[1]; // sencond p tag
```

Comment: this is exactly my answer my friend.. you copied it.

Comment: No I didn't copied we wrote at the same time

Comment: Look at the time i wrote vs the time you wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the accepted answer you can safely use the `nth-child(n)` selector however that's perhaps more suitable for dynamically accessing the `n`'th child. Such as;

```
var n = 2;
document.querySelector(`.demo div p:nth-child(${n})`);
```

On the other hand CSS selector combinators are also very powerful. If you simply want to access the very next `<p>` coming after the first `<p>` which is directly under a `<div>` which is directly under an element with `.demo` class. So `".demo > div > p + p"` should be sufficient. In this particular case we don't have any nested `div`s under `.demo` so we can also do like `".demo div p + p"`.

```js
var el = document.querySelector(".demo > div > p + p");
console.log(el.textContent)
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  <div>
    <p>Some Text...</p>
    <p><b>Author:</b> Author Name</p>
    <p>Some Text...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```